# Shifting a QGraphicsItem's "graphic"

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qpainter, qgraphicsscene

I have a QGraphicsItem with a custom graphic as shown below in the top half of the figure, where the red circle is the `shape()` of the item:

[image: qgraphicsitem]

Is there a way to preserve the graphic but just shift it like shown in the bottom half of the figure?

Comment: I think this is now resolved at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11057778/183339

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, you can move QGraphicsItem without shape. Shape is bounded to QGraphicsItem.
It changes its co-ordinates according to QGraphicsItem.

If you want to achieve something like your second half of the fig. You need to have two QGraphicsItems (one is your red outer circle and second your inner graphics item).